# How to segue to View Controller from skview

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, segue

As simple as this question may seem, I just couldn't figure it out. To the overflow community, I am using sprite kit to create a simple game, However when you lose the game I want to programmatically segue back to another viewController (basically the home screen). from The game scene I do not get access to "performSegueWithIdentifier" I've seen a couple answers that relate to this topic however non of them are in swift ... Any solutions? 
links of related questions include : [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142632/how-to-perform-segue-from-within-a-skscene)
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding SKViews. SKViews are just like a normal UIViews, they take place within a normal ViewController. You will therefore need to segue from the ViewController which is presenting your SKView.

I have the same issue in a game I have created ([Ninja-Shooter](https://github.com/AlexChesters/Ninja-Shooter)). In my game, whenever I want to segue back the home screen I pass a value to `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`. Then in my ViewController I am constantly listening for any change in that value, if the value does change, then I perform a segue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see what you mean by what an SKView is , but what function can allow you to constantly listen for changes in value in your view controller ? @Alex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916702/go-back-to-view-controller-from-skscene   this link actually describes exactly what I wish to accomplish, can anyone translate to swift?

Comment: Admittedly mine is a poor implementation (I am still relatively new to Swift), I have a function which runs every 0.1 second which checks if the value has changed

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that using NSNotification Center Can in fact derive the results I was looking for. If any one in the future needs detailed code I will edit to provide that